# Subquery to avoid function SQL in WHERE

Tags: mysql

Could you tell me which is the best option, I have a procedure, which use a function in the clause where, I read that sql don't use the index if in the clause where exists a function, then I decided create a subquery for making that the sql get filter information based on the index and then of that it use the function, but with a little amount of records.

This is the first option.

```
        SELECT a, b, c
        FROM table  
        WHERE f = 0
        AND d <> 1
        AND HOUR(TIMEDIFF(Now(), A.hora)) <= 4 ;
```

And this is the another.

```
SELECT a,b,c
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT a, b, c,hora
        FROM table  
        WHERE f = 0
        AND d <> 1
    ) AS A
    WHERE  HOUR(TIMEDIFF(Now(), A.hora)) <= 4 ;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT...

Comment: Have you run these queries on your data? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't help at all or even make any difference.

If there were an index on `f` and/or `d` it can be used for both queries.

But an index on or including `hora` (which is falsely referenced in the first query BTW) can not be used, for both queries.

In fact, I suspect the `WHERE` clause of the outer query of second query just gets pushed down into the subquery and both of your queries yield the same execution plan.

What you really should have done is to get `hora` out of the functions. If I interpret it right you want to get all records where `hora` isn't more than four hours in the past. You could use

```
hora >= addtime(now(), '-4:00:00.000')
```

for that.

Answer (score 0):

if u have many rows in your table and want to check which query is working quickly and if it used indexes that you have in your table, just run both queries with `EXPLAIN` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html. And MySQL will tell u which indexes it used and how many rows went out, so u could choose better one.